# how to remove force quotes for only one column in csv file

Tags: ruby

I'm generating some CSV output using Ruby's built-in CSV. Everything works fine, but the customer wants the price field in the output should be without double-quotes.

So the output looks like this:

> "10789852616","Studentska-trgovina","27.80","EUR",

The customer wants to like this:

> "10789852616","Studentska-trgovina",27.80,"EUR",

Comment: have you tried `to_f` method `"27.80".to_f => 27.80`

Comment: Thanks I will try now

Answer (score 0):

Try `.to_f` it returns the result of interpreting leading characters in str as a floating point number. Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored. If there is not a valid number at the start of str, 0.0 is returned.